# docker-sync: command not found

Tags: bash, docker, rubygems

```
$ gem install docker-sync

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/docker-sync-0.5.9/Thorfile

$ sudo gem install docker-sync

Successfully installed docker-sync-0.5.9
Parsing documentation for docker-sync-0.5.9
Done installing documentation for docker-sync after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

$ docker-sync
-bash: docker-sync: command not found
```

I have tried to install docker-sync on my Mac OSX 10.14.2 but bash does never found the command. Also not after reboot. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If only your user (let's call it `user1`) needs `docker-sync`, then I suggest you to install the gem for user `user1` by running (as `user1`, not `root`) :

```
gem install --user-install docker-sync
```

Then, add `docker-sync` binary location (probably `~/.gem/ruby/<ruby_version>/bin`) to your `PATH` :

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/<ruby_version>/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

another version of this can be

```
gem install docker-sync --user-install -n /usr/local/bin
```

you will not have to export the path if you install this way